# binding ng-model to ionic popover

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Need help on this.I created the following code `http://play.ionic.io/app/b9c6216003eb`
When the user click on the search button after typing in some text,if the text is present in 'myArray' then it should be displayed in the popover otherwise nothing

Answer (score 0):

Implemented example whenever text field contains more than 4 characters, it shows popup and hides popup when it is empty.
Following is the link
http://play.ionic.io/app/1b21d83b71ba